# Use a parameter as pattern in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

Is it possible to make a generic function that would take either Foo or Bar as an argument and would return a function that uses that argument in its pattern matching?

For instance, if I have

```
isFoo :: SomeData -> Bool
isFoo (Foo _) = True
isFoo _       = False

isBar :: SomeData -> Bool
isBar (Bar _) = True
isBar _       = False
```

Is there a way to create a generic function, something like

```
checkType :: SomeClass -> SomeData -> Bool
checkType (SomeClass _) = True
checkType _ = False
```

I realize the situation looks a little odd, and the actual use case is a little more complex, but the problem is identical.

---

The actual code I'm trying to refactor is the following

```
isString :: [LispVal] -> ThrowsError LispVal
isString [(String _)] = return $ Bool True
isString ((String _):xs) = isString xs >>= unpackBool >>= return . Bool
isString _ = return $ Bool False

isSymbol :: [LispVal] -> ThrowsError LispVal
isSymbol [(Atom _)] = return $ Bool True
isSymbol ((Atom _):xs) = isSymbol xs >>= unpackBool >>= return . Bool
isSymbol _ = return $ Bool False

isNumber :: [LispVal] -> ThrowsError LispVal
isNumber [(Number _)] = return $ Bool True
isNumber ((Number _):xs) = isNumber xs >>= unpackBool >>= return . Bool
isNumber _ = return $ Bool False
```

So I'd like some way to make this more dry

Comment: You mean if there's a generic way to check if a value was constructed with a particular constructor? No, I don't think so. Actually, I'm fairly sure that's not possible. Maybe if you'd describe your use case we could figure out a way to do what you wanna do anyway?

Comment: Perhaps if you tell us a little about what you are actually trying to do, there could be a better way. See [the xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/169090). Note: I'm a beginner in Haskell, so I wouldn't really know.

Comment: Haskell has a lot of Generic Programming libraries which might allow this kind of thing.

Comment: I think you van do it with Template Hsskell.

Comment: Also, for instances of `Generic` constructor names are avaiable as strings, and it's derivable. I'm not sure you can automatically derive something more efficient though.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[`Prism`s](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.10.1/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html) from the [`lens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.10.1) library can act as "first-class patterns". To define prisms for your datatype:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens

data SomeData = Foo Int 
              | Bar Char

-- Will create prisms named _Foo and _Bar
$(makePrisms ''SomeData)
```

Since `Prism`s are valid `Fold`s, we can pass them to the [`has`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.10.1/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v%3ahas) function from `Control.Lens.Fold`:

```
*Main> has _Foo (Foo 5)
True
*Main> has _Bar (Foo 5)
False
```

Another interesting application of prisms as first-class patterns is "overriding" the behaviour of a function for cases in which the argument matches the prism. You can use [`outside`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.10.1/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html#t%3aoutside) from [`Control.Lens.Prism`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.10.1/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html) to do that. `outside` is a function that takes a `Prism` and returns a `Lens` for functions, that allows you to "set" the special case. For example:

```
functionToOverride :: SomeData -> Int
functionToOverride = const 5

-- If the arg is a Foo, return the contained int + 1 
newFunction :: SomeData -> Int
newFunction = functionToOverride & outside _Foo .~ succ
```

Testing both functions:

```
*Main> functionToOverride (Foo 77)
5
*Main> newFunction (Bar 'a')
5
*Main> newFunction (Foo 77)
78
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Data.Data
import Data.Typeable

data Foo a = Foo1 a | Foo2 a deriving (Data, Typeable)

data Bar a = Bar1 a | Bar2 a deriving (Data, Typeable)

checkType :: Data a => Constr -> a -> Bool
checkType c v = c == toConstr v
```

example

```
zeroFoo1 = Foo1 (0 :: Int)

isFoo1 = checkType (toConstr zeroFoo1)
```

to generalize over `a` your `checkType`, you need a constant value (e.g. `mempty`) for each constructor.

(really, the only trick is `toConstr a == toConstr b`)

Answer (score 1):

Currently this isn't possible, although some extensions that would allow it are in the works.

The closest workaround currently is probably to provide a function that matches on the appropriate pattern:

```
isString :: [LispVal] -> ThrowsError LispVal
isString [(String _)] = return $ Bool True
isString ((String _):xs) = isString xs >>= unpackBool >>= return . Bool
isString _ = return $ Bool False
```

You can replace the top pattern match with a function:

```
isLispVal :: (LispVal -> Bool) -> [LispVal] -> ThrowsError LispVal
isLispVal p [x] | p x = return $ Bool True
isLispVal p (x:xs) | p x = isLispVal p xs >>= unpackBool >>= return . Bool
isLispVal p _ = return $ Bool False
```

When I've done this, I've often ended up needed proper lenses instead of just predicate functions, but it depends on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your `isString` function is just a lifting of the `all` function.

Consider this:

```
data LispVal = Str String | B Bool | Sym String | Num Integer

isLispStr (Str _) = True
isLispStr _ = False

isLispNum (Num _) = True
isLispNum _ = False

isLispSym (Sym _) = True
isLispSym _ = False

-- etc. for the other LispVal constructors.
```

Now consider these functions:

```
isString' :: [LispVal] -> LispVal
isString' = B . all isLispStr

isSymbol' :: [LispVal] -> LispVal
isSymbol' = B . all isLispSym

-- ...
```

These are the "pure" (i.e. non-monadic) versions of your `isString` and `isSymbol` functions.
The monadic versions are just:

```
isString = return . isString'
isSymbol = return . isSymbol'
```

etc.