How to remove speicific value constructor in a list using traversal
data Fruit = Apple Int
           | Banana Color Int
           
data Color = Red
           | Green
           
let basket = [Apple 3,Banana Red 30,Apple 6]

The goal is to keep Banana only
How to remove all Apple {} in the list basket ? using traversal (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.3.2/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html) ?
Once the traversal  is built then I can remove them , modify them (over) , change them (set)
Thank you !

You mat want to look at filter function.

@n.m.couldbeanAI filter only filter, but traversal would able to modify and replace selected.

What do you mean by traversal? The standard traverse function cannot filter at all.

@Carl https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.3.2/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html.    the Traversal shall able to focus 0 or N elements inside a structure

You cannot modify a list in place. You can use a Traversal to build a modified copy I guess, but it won't buy you anything new.

"One consequence of this requirement is that a Traversal needs to leave the same number of elements as a candidate for subsequent Traversal that it started with."

I think you could 1) transform basket to [[Apple 3], [Banana Red 30], [Apple 6]], then 2) replace all sublists not containing Banana with empty lists, yielding [[], [Banana Red 30], []], then 3) flatten the result to [Banana Red 30]. Then you aren't traversing over a [Fruit] value, but a [[Fruit]] value.

Oh. Are you asking for a Traversal that only targets Bananas? That's not really the same thing as one that removes everything else. While it can be used to get a list of the Bananas in a structure, it can't extract values in a way that preserve structure when there's a nested data structure involved.

It can't be done using Traversals. Neither traverse from base nor the traversals from lens allow for that.
The reason is that traversals have the important property that they don't change the overall "shape" of the container. They can't add or remove elements. As the docs for Traversable say:

Functors representing data structures that can be transformed to structures of the same shape

It's true that the lens documentation says that traversals let you "focus" on certain elements of a structure. But what is meant is that you can set those elements, or modify them. You can't delete them.

If you are looking for a Traversable-like class for containers that allow (potentially effectful) filtering operations, there's Filterable and Witherable from the witherable package.

But in your case, I would simply do something like
removeApples :: [Fruit] -> [Fruit]
removeApples = mapMaybe (\f -> case f of
   Apple {} -> Nothing
   other -> Just other)

removeApples2 :: [Fruit] -> [Fruit]
removeApples2 = foldMap (\f -> case f of
   Apple {} -> []
   other -> [other])

removeApples3 :: [Fruit] -> [Fruit]
removeApples3 fruits = do -- list monad
   fruit <- fruits
   case fruit of 
    Apple {} -> []
    other -> [other]

removeApples4 :: [Fruit] -> [Fruit]
removeApples4 = filter (\f -> case f of
   Apple {} -> False
   other -> True)


Is there a way that parameterised the Apple to function signature as it looks generic if user want to remove Banana next time ? that would save rewriting almost same function (just replace Apple with Banana ) again

@ShawnZhang The "lens" package (also the "optics" package) has the concept of a Prism. You can create them for a sum type and use them as a sort of "first-class patterns" to define your predicate functions, with the help of combinators like has or hasn't. An example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774475/use-a-parameter-as-pattern-in-haskell#20774967
